# How to make emacs not crash when converting binary file to UTF-8

Tags: character-encoding, revert-buffer, crash

When I run `revert-buffer-with-coding-system [RET] UTF-8` Emacs crashes.

This is the file I'm trying to revert.

```
\0  

 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿĀāĂăĄąĆćĈĉĊċČčĎďĐđĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĲĳĴĵĶķĸĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłŃńŅņŇňŉŊŋŌōŎŏŐőŒœŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞşŠšŢţŤťŦŧŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵŶŷŸŹźŻżŽžſƀƁƂƃƄƅƆƇƈƉƊƋƌƍƎƏƐƑƒƓƔƕƖƗƘƙƚƛƜƝƞƟƠơƢƣƤƥƦƧƨƩƪƫƬƭƮƯưƱƲƳƴƵƶƷƸƹƺƻƼƽƾƿǀǁǂǃǄǅǆǇǈǉǊǋǌǍǎǏǐǑǒǓǔǕǖǗǘǙǚǛǜǝǞǟǠǡǢǣǤǥǦǧǨǩǪǫǬǭǮǯǰǱǲǳǴǵǶǷǸǹǺǻǼǽǾǿȀȁȂȃȄȅȆȇȈȉȊȋȌȍȎȏȐȑȒȓȔȕȖȗȘșȚțȜȝȞȟȠȡȢȣȤȥȦȧȨȩȪȫȬȭȮȯȰȱȲȳȴȵȶȷȸȹȺȻȼȽȾȿɀɁɂɃɄɅɆɇɈɉɊɋɌɍɎɏɐɑɒɓɔɕɖɗɘəɚɛɜɝɞɟɠɡɢɣɤɥɦɧɨɩɪɫɬɭɮɯɰɱɲɳɴɵɶɷɸɹɺɻɼɽɾɿʀʁʂʃʄʅʆʇʈʉʊʋʌʍʎʏʐʑʒʓʔʕʖʗʘʙʚʛʜʝʞʟʠʡʢʣʤʥʦʧʨʩʪʫʬʭʮʯʰʱʲʳʴʵʶʷʸʹʺʻʼʽʾʿˀˁ˂˃˄˅ˆˇˈˉˊˋˌˍˎˏːˑ˒˓˔˕˖˗˘˙˚˛˜˝˞˟ˠˡˢˣˤ˥˦˧˨˩˪˫ˬ˭ˮ˯˰˱˲˳˴˵˶˷˸˹˺˻˼˽˾˿̴̵̶̷̸̡̢̧̨̛̖̗̘̙̜̝̞̟̠̣̤̥̦̩̪̫̬̭̮̯̰̱̲̳̹̺̻̼͇͈͉͍͎̀́̂̃̄̅̆̇̈̉̊̋̌̍̎̏̐̑̒̓̔̽̾̿̀́͂̓̈́͆͊͋͌̕̚ͅ͏͓͔͕͖͙͚͐͑͒͗͛ͣͤͥͦͧͨͩͪͫͬͭͮͯ͘͜͟͢͝͞͠͡ͰͱͲͳʹ͵Ͷͷ͸͹ͺͻͼͽ;Ϳ΀΁΂΃΄΅Ά·ΈΉΊ΋Ό΍ΎΏΐΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡ΢ΣΤΥΦΧΨΩΪΫάέήίΰαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρςστυφχψωϊϋόύώϏϐϑϒϓϔϕϖϗϘϙϚϛϜϝϞϟϠϡϢϣϤϥϦϧϨϩϪϫϬϭϮϯϰϱϲϳϴϵ϶ϷϸϹϺϻϼϽϾϿЀЁЂЃЄЅІЇЈЉЊЋЌЍЎЏАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяѐёђѓєѕіїјљњћќѝўџѠѡѢѣѤѥѦѧѨѩѪѫѬѭѮѯѰѱѲѳѴѵѶѷѸѹѺѻѼѽѾѿҀҁ҂҃҄҅҆҇҈҉ҊҋҌҍҎҏҐґҒғҔҕҖҗҘҙҚқҜҝҞҟҠҡҢңҤҥҦҧҨҩҪҫҬҭҮүҰұҲҳҴҵҶҷҸҹҺһҼҽҾҿӀӁӂӃӄӅӆӇӈӉӊӋӌӍӎӏӐӑӒӓӔӕӖӗӘәӚӛӜӝӞӟӠӡӢӣӤӥӦӧӨөӪӫӬӭӮӯӰӱӲӳӴӵӶӷӸӹӺӻӼӽӾӿԀԁԂԃԄԅԆԇԈԉԊԋԌԍԎԏԐԑԒԓԔԕԖԗԘԙԚԛԜԝԞԟԠԡԢԣԤԥԦԧԨԩԪԫԬԭԮԯ԰ԱԲԳԴԵԶԷԸԹԺԻԼԽԾԿՀՁՂՃՄՅՆՇՈՉՊՋՌՍՎՏՐՑՒՓՔՕՖ՗՘ՙ՚՛՜՝՞՟ՠաբգդեզէըթժիլխծկհձղճմյնշոչպջռսվտրցւփքօֆևֈ։֊֋֌֍֎֏֐ְֱֲֳִֵֶַָֹֺֻּֽ֑֖֛֢֣֤֥֦֧֪֚֭֮֒֓֔֕֗֘֙֜֝֞֟֠֡֨֩֫֬֯־ֿ׀ׁׂ׃ׅׄ׆ׇ׈׉׊׋׌׍׎׏אבגדהוזחטיךכלםמןנסעףפץצקרשת׫׬׭׮ׯװױײ׳״׵׶׷׸׹׺׻׼׽׾׿؀؁؂؃؄؅؆؇؈؉؊؋،؍؎؏ؘؙؚؐؑؒؓؔؕؖؗ؛؜؝؞؟ؠءآأؤإئابةتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغػؼؽؾؿـفقكلمنهوىيًٌٍَُِّْٕٖٜٟٓٔٗ٘ٙٚٛٝٞ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٪٫٬٭ٮٯٰٱٲٳٴٵٶٷٸٹٺٻټٽپٿڀځڂڃڄڅچڇڈډڊڋڌڍڎڏڐڑڒړڔڕږڗژڙښڛڜڝڞڟڠڡڢڣڤڥڦڧڨکڪګڬڭڮگڰڱڲڳڴڵڶڷڸڹںڻڼڽھڿۀہۂۃۄۅۆۇۈۉۊۋیۍێۏېۑےۓ۔ەۖۗۘۙۚۛۜ۝۞ۣ۟۠ۡۢۤۥۦۧۨ۩۪ۭ۫۬ۮۯ۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹ۺۻۼ۽۾ۿ܀܁܂܃܄܅܆܇܈܉܊܋܌܍܎܏ܐܑܒܓܔܕܖܗܘܙܚܛܜܝܞܟܠܡܢܣܤܥܦܧܨܩܪܫܬܭܮܯܱܴܷܸܹܻܼܾ݂݄݆݈ܰܲܳܵܶܺܽܿ݀݁݃݅݇݉݊݋݌ݍݎݏݐݑݒݓݔݕݖݗݘݙݚݛݜݝݞݟݠݡݢݣݤݥݦݧݨݩݪݫݬݭݮݯݰݱݲݳݴݵݶݷݸݹݺݻݼݽݾݿހށނރބޅކއވމފދތލގޏސޑޒޓޔޕޖޗޘޙޚޛޜޝޞޟޠޡޢޣޤޥަާިީުޫެޭޮޯްޱ޲޳޴޵޶޷޸޹޺޻޼޽޾޿
```

I would like to know how to accomplish this operation without Emacs abruptly exiting. I'm working with GNU Emacs 26.1.

Comment: Emacs should not crash. Consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Include your file in the bug report, providing a recipe for the crash that starts with `emacs -Q` (no init file.).

Comment: Indeed, just pasting this in a buffer triggered a segmentation fault in emacs 26.1, but not in 27.0.50.  By the way, you mean `revert-buffer-with-coding-system`, don't you?

Comment: @JeanPierre Yes `revert-buffer-with-coding-system` is right. I'll change it in the question.